# jQuery Selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need a bit of help getting the values from these HTML elements with jQuery;

```
<ul class='post-meta'>
<li><span class='post-meta-key'>uniqueidA:</span> value1</li>
<li><span class='post-meta-key'>uniqueidB:</span> value2</li>
</ul>
```

These are dynamic values and I need to say get 'value1' from 'uniqueidA' and 'value2' from 'uniqueidB'

Comment: Consider using `<span class='post-meta-value'>`

Comment: if its `uniqueidA` (ie a unique identifier) why not use the same thing as an id attribute ? `<li id="uniqueidA"><label>uniqueidA:</label><span>value1</span></li>` and then use `$("#uniqueidA").children().filter('span').text()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = $(".post-meta-key:contains('uniqueidA')").get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
var b = $(".post-meta-key:contains('uniqueidB')").get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;

alert(a +" "+ b);
```

See it on jSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jay2S/

If you need the values without any whitespace you can use jQuery.trim()

```
alert($.trim(a) +" "+ $.trim(b));
```

There may be more factors in your particular situation, but this is a quick and dirty way to get it done.

Comment: Smart. nextSibling is a text node in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Selectors won't help much here.

You will have to select the parent: `$('.post-meta-key:contains('uniqueidA'))`

Then you will have to write your own javascript to parse the contents. Or you can copy the parent to a temporary object, then `.remove()` the span, leaving you with a space and your value.

As Šime Vidas suggests, re-write your HTML so a selector will work directly.

Answer (score 0):

well, why dont put the value text inside a tag with a specific id? could it be an option for you?

```
<ul class='post-meta'>
    <li><span class='post-meta-key'>uniqueidA:</span><span id="uniqueidA">value1</span></li>
    <li><span class='post-meta-key'>uniqueidB:</span><span id="uniqueidB">value2</span></li>
</ul>
```

does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

A definition list would better suit your requirements:

```
<dl class='post-meta'>
    <dt>uniqueidA</dt> <dd>value1</dd>
    <dt>uniqueidA</dt> <dd>value2</dd>
</dl>
```

... then just use `next()` to jump to the value.

Answer (score 0):

To get the uniqueid and value, we need to grab both the `text()` and `nodeType` values.

```
var x = $('.post-meta-key');
var y = $('li').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
});
alert(x.eq(0).text() + " " + y.eq(0).text()); //This will get you only the first `<li>`
```

To get the value of all `<li>'s` we need to create a for loop. See working example below.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/3CcjF/1/